# Define a database for app if a valid one doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I'm in the middle of writing this NodeJS/MySQL app that expects a particular database format. This thing needs to run on machines where I'm not going to want to be doing much, if any setup beforehand.

I could, of course, go through the code each time and make the appropriate database manually. But I was wondering if it was possible to define the database in a way that if it doesn't exist in the SQL server, it's constructed as required.

For example, right now I'd do this:

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'password',
    password: 'username',
    database: 'app-db'
});
```

If the database `app-db` doesn't exist, I'd like to create the database, define all the tables, and the fields inside them, in one go, such that if my app runs on a server without the appropriate database, it just constructs a blank one.

Comment: You could invoke a MySQL script to check this. Read about [if-not-exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html)